# Is There a Standard Container Which Works Well for Resorting?

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, vector, containers

I'm looking for a container which works well for sorting according to an external value. So for example, let's say my elements are: `pair<char, int>` The key to this pair is *not* unique. So let's say for example I have:

- `'a'`, `0`
- `'j'`, `13`
- `'m'`, `42`
- `'z'`, `100`

I want to maintain the sorting of this container by nearness to `char foo`, which may change, at which point I'd need to "Dynamically Sort" the container. So for example let's say that `foo` starts out as `'m'` I'd want these elements sorted into the order.

- `'m'`, `42`
- `'j'`, `13`
- `'a'`, `0`
- `'z'`, `100`

Now `foo` changes to `'i'` I'd need to make a resort call on this container to get the ordering:

- `'j'`, `13`
- `'a'`, `0`
- `'m'`, `42`
- `'z'`, `100`

I know that I can do this with a `vector`. Is that my best choice? I'm really looking for something that works like a `map` but because of the inconsistency of the sort I can't use that.

Comment: Since sorted containers take the comparators as template arguments, the only way to change the sorting is to move the entire collection of elements into another type of container with the proper sorting. You are likely better off just using a `std::vector` and sorting it each time. If you want to use the containers with different sorting criteria interchangeably, it pretty much rules out all the implicitly sorted containers (unless you heavily template all of the code that might use them).

Comment: note that sorting for nearness to a different char is merely a rotation of sorting to nearness to any arbitrary character plus a small residual transformation, so you probably just need a vector and then rotate it accordingly

Comment: The contents are completely reordered, so I can't see how you could do better than a vector.

Comment: @user463035818 Oh man that's so insightful. Thank you. I'm trying to figure out how I can leverage that.

Comment: @user463035818 -- tempting as it is to think of this as a rotation, that's not right. Consider `a`, `b`, `z`; if we're sorting on nearness to `c`, the order is `b`, `a`, `z`; if we're sorting on nearness to `a`, the order is `a`, `b`, `z` (or, possibly, `a`, `z`, `b`)

Comment: @PeteBecker it is rotation plus a small residual transformation, ill try to outline the idea in an answer...

Comment: @user463035818 -- by all means!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort something relative to X, starting with a sorted list, simply find where 'X' should be in the list.

Now merge (as in `std::merge`) the two ranges "after X" and "before X, backwards".

The trick to making this efficient is to not actually move anything.  Apply the "sort" as a lazy or wrapping operation.

How exactly you do this will depend on what operations you need.  If you are writing a priority queue, you might use a `std::map` and naively insert things.

Then to find the lowest element, use lower/upper bound and compare the (up to) two candidates to see which is "lower".

That'll give you O(lg n) pop lowest.

If you need to iterate in that order, you'll have to write a 'merging forward range'.  A 'merging forward range' owns two forward iterator ranges and a comparison function object; its iterators are forward iterators, and keep one iterator in each range, and dereferencing and advancing operates on the "lowest" one (where end is never lowest), and `==` works element-wise.

That is O(1) advancing over the container.

Comment: I've accepted, cause this is exactly what I was looking for. I must say though this sounds like something there is boilerplate for. I'm starting to write my own... but if you happened to know of some boilerplate for the range I'd be very interested.

Comment: @JonathanMee No, I'm unaware of merge iterators being written by anyone.  It does seem something quite useful.  "rangesv3 lazy merge" doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of simplicity lets say you are sorting a container of integers according to distance to a given integer, then consider this example (already sorted in increasing order):

```
1 2 5 12 20 100
```

Lets say you want to sort this according to distance to 10, then the result is

```
12 5 2 1 20 100
```

Now sorted according to distance to 15

```
12 20 5 2 1 100
```

The elements appear to be completely reordered, however if you think of the sorting in two steps it is rather obvious how the different sorts are related.

Lets start again with the original

```
1 2 5 12 20 100
     ^------------ 10
        ^--------- 15
```

Now if you sort according to distance to 10 you already have half of the job done, because the two parts

```
5 2 1          // first part reversed
12 20 100      // second part
```

are already sorted, you merely have to merge them (simple O(N)). Same for sorting according to distance to 15:

```
12 5 2 1   // already sorted
20 100     // already sorted
```

merge them in O(N) and you are done.

This is just to outline the idea. I would maybe use a `std::vector` that is simply sorted in increasing order and then creating the desired sorting is rather cheap. One could even think keeping the `vector` itself always sorted in increasing order and only provide iterators for differently sorted views.